# node_modules\@react-navigation\elements\src\assets\back-icon-mask.png: Attempt to access memory outside buffer bounds

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am developing React-Native Expo.
When I build the app, there is an error

```
Android Bundling failed

node_modules\@react-navigation\elements\src\assets\back-icon-mask.png: Attempt to access memory outside buffer bounds
```

[image: This is package.json]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you try to render large-size files. You should consider compressing or converting the images to a smaller size.
Webp is one of the best formats to store your images in. I recommend you to convert it in this format if possible

Comment: as you can see, that error comes from node_modules. so it doesn't due to image size. I reinstalled node_modules and restart expo with clear cache and it works fine